# AngularJS - dynamically remove directive from element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What is the proper way to dynamically add or remove directive from compiled and linked element?

I have a page that has bunch of inputs there (the list is pretty long, so i want to come up with a general solution). What i want to do is to disable all the inputs if specific flag set. I can do this by using jQuery's element.prop('disabled', true).

The problem of such approach is that if any of inputs have ng-disabled or ng-enabled directives attached, then on any their expression modification they will override previously set 'disabled' property. But I want them to not override my global flag.

I came up with the solution to add another bunch of watchers for ng-disabled or ng-enabled expression, but it seems to be not the best approach.

What I want to do, is to remove most of directives attached to the element and set appropriate attributes myself. But if I recompile and relink the element, and then replace it in the document, then I will get a memory leak, as the old element will be de-attached from the DOM document tree, and will remain in memory. I cannot destroy element's scope either, because those elements basically use whole page's main scope.

Comment: Have you tried [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf)

Comment: Your issue isn't all that clear to me, but why do you need to remove the DOM nodes if all you're trying to do is disable them based on a flag. I'm also unclear as to what "global flag" means in your context.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you would like to do with the inputs. If they have this <input ng-disable="true"/> you also want something that will over-ride ng-disable?

Comment: No, ng-disabled="true" was fine. But ng-disabled="false" would remove disabled attribute, which I wanted to override.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<div ng-show="someBoolean" >Some text or nested element</div>
```

or instead of "someBoolean" you can attach a function that resolves to a boolean. To set your boolean you could attach a ng-click to your input that updates your model/boolean value

```
<button type="button" ng-click="setBoolean()">Some text or nested element </button>
```

Because of angulars two way data binding the ng-show will be updated upon completion of the next digest cycle